# initiate a restore point on windows boot

Tags: windows, windows-10

i have a situation involving a few dozen PCs that all came to the conclusion
its great time to stop in the "Advanced startup" menu. and wait for a keystroke.

basically `<right key>, <enter>, <left>, etc...`

is there a sane way to automate this?
i need to get to the first restore point and start it.
googling this leads to many screen captured tutorials as to "how to do it" but not automate it, on boot.

i only have a network and usb ports accessible

[Boot to Advanced Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I do not think it is possible without a script or task that runs at login.